# numbers in row count

Tags: python, count, numbers

How to count how many times even numbers in row?
For example: 3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 7, 3, 7, 4, 2 (should be '2' = two times even numbers in row - 6,8 and 4,2.

```
s = [3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 7, 3, 7, 4, 2]
print(len([i for i in s if i % 2 == 0]))
```

This one gives how many times (5) even numbers in general. But need how many times even numbers in row. Could anyone please help with solution to get the point.

If  you have 3 even numbers in a row. eg: 2,6,4 should be 2(two times)

Comment: what if you have 3 even numbers in a row. eg: 2,6,4. Should that be counted as 1 or 2?

Comment: should be 2(two times)

Comment: then you just need to iterate each element and compare it with the next one. If both are even increment a counter.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki if next to next element is also even then this will again lead to increase of counter

Comment: yes, 3 consecutive even numbers should result in a counter increased 2 times. you just need to check a number with the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach using *zip()* and *sum()*

```
s = [3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 7, 3, 7, 4, 2]

count = sum(x % 2 + y % 2 == 0 for x, y in zip(s, s[1:]))

print(count)
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Comment: @assume_irrational_is_rational I quote from the question "If you have 3 even numbers in a row. eg: 2,6,4 should be 2(two times)" - i.e., the 4,2,4 sequence increases the count by 2

Comment: That's why I asked what is the behavior when 3 consecutive even numbers are found.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `itertools.groupby` #### i used groupby to check more than two consecutive even numbers

```
from itertools import groupby
s = [3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 7, 3, 7, 4, 2]
len(list(filter(lambda x: (not x[0]%2) and (len(list(x[1]))>1),groupby(s, key=lambda x: x%2))))
# output : 2
```

working: groupby with group the list with the keys which are even, and then we check the length of that group if it is greater than 1 then that means consecutive even numbers.

##### without itertools

```
i = 0
cnt = 0
while i<len(s):
  j=i
  while (i<len(s) and s[i]%2==0):
    i+=1
  if i>len(s):
    break
  if i-j>1:
    cnt+=1
  i+=1
print(cnt)
```

Time Complexity: O(n)

Comment: except itertools.groupby?

Comment: I need to check

Comment: I'm quite against using itertools. Sure, it might be very clean an fast, but if a user cannot make code to just check if two consecutive numbers are even (it's a simple loop where you compare one number and the next), then directly giving a solution that uses itertools will result in learning nothing. A slightly different problem and will be here again asking for a solution. Try making a code that counts 3 consecutive odd numbers.

Comment: @assume_irrational_is_rational Try your "without itertools" suggestion with [3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 7, 3, 7, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1]

Comment: Yes, I  missed one condition for edge case, now it will work fine.